# How to make one of the item of my navigation drawer as an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want to make one of the item of my navigation drawer as an expendableListView, I know about ExpendableListView, but don't know how to integrate it inside a navigation drawer and specially make it appear as the other items of my navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/home_content" />

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start|top"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

   <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
   </LinearLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Updated:
on your groupExpandListener write condition

```
expandedListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                if (groupPosition == 0) { // EXPAND
                    expandedListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                } else if(groupPosition != 0 {
                    // Intent...
                    // Do your stuff
                }  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will make all my navigationdrawer as an Expandable ListView, However I want that just one item  will be an expandableListview, the other will be just simple item

Comment: Updated my answer kindly check it once again